# How do I change the tomcat's server default port in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot

Using Server.port in application.properties doesn't seem to work with Spring Boot 3+.
Any idea how do I change the application's port from application.properties when using Spring Boot 3.
(I am using using Spring Boot 3.0.4).

I tried adding server.port to the application.properties but it didn't work. Attaching a screenshot for ref.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g8iZ.jpg

Comment: Hey Akshay, i have the same problem as you when trying to deploy spring boot 3 application in tomcat10 server (not embedded tomcat).  Were u able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with spring boot 3.0.5 and setting `server.port=8081` in `src/main/resources/application.properties` worked perfectly.

Comment: How did u test this? Did u use embedded tomcat or it was a standalone tomcat10 installation. I have the same problem as op when its a standalone tomcat10 installation in which you deploy the war

Comment: I tested with embedded tomcat